# Using a batch file to copy files with a wildcard in the directory path?

Tags: batch-file, wildcard

I want a batch file to copy files from a folder, which changes every month, to another folder but it seems Windows command prompt doesn't like wildcards.

Example:
I want to copy the folder `media1` and containing files in this directory:

```
K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI81711001\FI81711001\FI81711_AHDF.001\OM_LOCAL_FLOPPY_1.44MB_S520_v1_1\media1
```

To this directory `K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\`.

But the `1711` part of folders `FI81711001` changes every month and I can't figure out how to get wildcards to work in scripting.

I've tried the following scripts:

```
robocopy "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*\FI8*\FI8*\OM_LOCAL*\media1" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\" 

copy "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*\FI8*\FI8*\OM_LOCAL*\media1" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\" 

xcopy "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*\FI8*\FI8*\OM_LOCAL*\media1" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\" 

for /D %%D in (K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*\FI8*\FI8*\OM_LOCAL*\) do copy "%%~D\media1\" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\"
```

When I run the `For` script I get `%%D was unexpected at this time.`

Comment: Welcome to SO! :-) What have you tried so far with the script? Could you add that to your question by editing?

Comment: `*` in the positions you've indicated means "starts with [FI8]" - do you mean that the `*` is replaced by the date - and if so, in what format? Do you want just the files found to be copied or do you want some variety of directory substructure - remembering that the subtree below `..._6` can be replicated, but not into the indicated directory (which would lead to an attempt to copy files to *themselves*). Do the file/directorynames contain any non-alphanumeric characters that have significance to `cmd` like `%!()^&+` ?

Comment: you forgot to quote the `<path\filename>` in your `for` line.

Comment: `for /D %%D in ("K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*\FI8*\FI8*\OM_LOCAL*") do xcopy "%%~D\media1\" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\"`

Still doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 1):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76"
SET "destdir=U:\Eng"
SET "dt=1711"

FOR /d /r "%sourcedir%" %%a IN (*) DO (
 ECHO %%a|FINDSTR /i "\FI8%dt%.*\FI8%dt%.*\FI8%dt%.*\OM_.*\media1" >NUL
 IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 (
  ECHO XCOPY "%%a\*" "%destdir%\"
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

We're still in the dark about precisely what needs to be copied where. I've assumed you want the files in `....\media1` for the appropriate day copied to some known directory (My test setup uses `U:` in place of `K:`)

With clarification of what needs to be copied and where, this can be refined.

Note that `dt` is set to the 4-character date sequence (**don't** use `date` for this variable - it's a reserved name). How you derive it - well, there are many articles on SO about how to extract date data, as it varies with user configuration. I've used a constant that could possibly be manually input if desired - depending on whether or not this is a scheduled job working on *today* or run at random.

Essentially, do a recursive directory scan, assigning each directoryname in turn to `%%a`. `echo` that name into `findstr`, looking for the string "\FI8*thedateinDT_anycharacters*\FI8*thedateinDT_anycharacters*\FI8*thedateinDT_anycharacters*\OM_*anycharacters*\media" in any case (the `/i` switch).

If the string is found, then `errorlevel` will be set to `0` which is not [1 or greater] hence the `xcopy` command will be `echoed` (for verification - remove the `echo` to *execute* the `xcopy`)

Comment: I want to copy the folder and files within "media1" to another directory but my problem is the folders that "media1" are in change each month.

Example, this month the "media1" folder and files are in `"K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI81711001\FI81711001\FI81711_AHDF.001\OM_LOCAL_FLOPPY_1.44MB_S520_v1_1\media1"`

But next month "media1" will be in `"K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI81712001\FI81712001\FI81712_AHDF.001\OM_LOCAL_FLOPPY_1.44MB_S520_v1_1\media1"`

Comment: Ultimately i want a script i don't have to modify every month.

Answer (score 0):

Besides missing quotes in your `for /D` approach to protect the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in the path, there is a conceptional problem:
you cannot put wildcards somewhere in the middle of a path, they can be used only in the very last item.
Since you have got a known fixed directory hierarchy depth, you could use nested [`for /D` loops](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html):

```cmd
for /D %%A in ("K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\FI8*") do (
    for /D %%B in ("%%~A\FI8*") do (
        for /D %%C in ("%%~B\FI8*") do (
            for /D %%D IN ("%%~C\OM_LOCAL*") do (
                xcopy /L /F /I /E "%%~D\media1\*.*" "K:\Eng\NAVDB\Navigation Databases\Current\FI8_Icelandair_B75_76\media"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

The `/L` option of the [`xcopy` command](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) prevents it from copying any files, the `/F` option displays both full source and destination paths; after having checked for the correct files that would be copied just remove `/L` (and also `/F` if you like) to actually copy them.